# composer drupal-core update fail because of zetacomponents/mail patch

Tags: updating, composer

I try to update a Drupalmachine on 9.4.5 site via composer 2.4.1.
`~/bin/composer.phar update drupal/core "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies` (see below for composer.json)

first try i can run it and get into interactive question that drupal/coder has multiple files changed (439) and what i want to do:

```
y - discard changes and apply the update
n - abort the update and let you manually clean things up
v - view modified files
d - view local modifications (diff)
s - stash changes and try to reapply them after the update
? - print help
```

i try to choose 'yes', but unfortunately i ran into a problem that patch 86 from zetacomponents/mail can not be applied and the update crashed. This patch seemed to be [merged](https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86) and old
composer try to install zetamail in version 1.9.3.
I tried to apply the patch manually on the files, but this
doesnt work either.

Here is the shortend version of the run through the update to the  error. After gathering the patches it got this errormessage, that the patches doesnt apply.

```
Applying patches for zetacomponents/mail
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/9d93748a36c7c5d44422911db1c98fb2f7067b34/tools/scripts/composer/patches/civicrm-custom-patches-zetacompoents-mail.patch (CiviCRM Custom Patches for ZetaCompoents mail)
    https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch (Allow single quotes to be used in return path)
   Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch

In Patches.php line 326:
                                                                                                                            
  Cannot apply patch Allow single quotes to be used in return path (https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch)!
```

Like suggested I provide the composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
  "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "role": ""
    }
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.8",
    "civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin": "~1.1",
    "civicrm/civicrm-core": "5.49.4",
    "civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8": "5.49.4",
    "civicrm/civicrm-packages": "5.49.4",
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.0",
    "drupal/civicrm_entity": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
    "drupal/content_access": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/context": "^4.1",
    "drupal/core": "^9.0.0",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.2",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
    "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/role_delegation": "^1.1",
    "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/token": "^1.10",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/upgrade_status": "^3.12",
    "drupal/views_aggregator": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.1",
    "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
    "drupal/webform_civicrm": "^6.0",
    "drush/drush": "^9.7.1 | ^10.0.0",
    "howtomakeaturn/pdfinfo": "1.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^4.0",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "drupal/core-dev": "^9"
  },
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true,
      "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
      "civicrm/composer-compile-plugin": true,
      "civicrm/composer-downloads-plugin": true,
      "civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin": true,
      "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
      "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
      "drupal/core-project-message": true,
      "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": true,
      "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ],
    "files": [
      "load.environment.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patchLevel": {
      "drupal/core": "-p2"
    },
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "locations": {
        "web-root": "web/"
      }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/core": [
        "type:drupal-core"
      ],
      "web/libraries/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-library"
      ],
      "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-module"
      ],
      "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-profile"
      ],
      "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-theme"
      ],
      "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-drush"
      ]
    },
    "civicrm-asset": {
      "path": "web/libraries/civicrm",
      "url": "/libraries/civicrm",
      "assets:packages": {
        "+include": [
          "kcfinder/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "enable-patching": "true",
    "compile-whitelist": [
      "civicrm/civicrm-core",
      "civicrm/composer-compile-lib"
    ],
    "compile-mode": "all"
  }
}
```

Is there a method to get the update done?

Comment: Please post details of the error you are asking about. There is absolutely nothing to go on here.

Comment: Sorry, i added a picture of the Error and edit it. I dont have more informations about the error.

Comment: Pictures of errors are not as useful as the actual text, for searching and copying.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i insert the text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Composer Patches error is clear. This project depends on a patch that no longer applies to its base branch or release.

This [particular patch was merged](https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86) more than one year ago so you probably do not need it. Any further Composer support would require a look at the composer.json file.

You can set `composer-exit-on-patch-failure": false` so you may proceed but this is a CiviCRM support question.

Comment: Thanks, I going to try it there. Thanks for your patience!